# How to repeat for loop iteration in Matlab if an error occurred

Tags: matlab, loops, iteration, continue

I have this code in MATLAB:

```
for i = 1: n
   a = randi([0 500]);
   function (a);
end
```

When there is error during the execution of `function(a)` in iteration `i=k` the program stops. Is there any way to make the program repeat the same iteration (when there is an error) with a new value of `a` and continue the execution?

Comment: The easiest way is to rewrite `function` so that it doesn't produce errors.

Comment: You don't. Other options include using a `while` loop with an incrementing counter based on the success of `function` or a [`try/catch`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/try.html) statement.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The solution to your problem is pretty simple. Just use [try, catch](http://ch.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/try.html).

**For loop that calls function**

```
for i=1:3
    a=randi([0 500]);
    try
        myfunction(a); %Statements that may throw an error
    catch
        %Code that is executed if myfunction throws error
    end
    disp(i) %Proves that the loop continuous if myfunction throws an error
end
```

**Function**

```
function b = myfunction(a)
    b=a;
    error('Error!!!') %Function throws error every time it gets called
end
```

**Output without try, catch**

```
Error using myfunction (line 3)
Error!!!

Error in For_Error (line 6)
    myfunction(a); %Statements that may throw an error
```

**Output with try, catch**

```
1

2

3
```

Comment: A `try/catch` block that is this indiscriminate is not a good idea. I highly recommend only catching [specific errors](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/error.html), as defined by `function`, and rethrowing ones that do not match.

Comment: `@user3288977` You do not have to write something into the `catch block` and depending on the application that could be totally okay. It is difficult to suggest something without knowing what your code is supposed to do. One possibility would be to create an error message to the user that explains what the cause of the exception might be (see [try, catch documentation](http://ch.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/try.html)).

Comment: What I understand is that `try/catch` skips the iteration where there is an error and continue the loop... But I want to re-execute the same iteration where the error occurs... I hope the idea is clear

Answer (score 1):

I think Kaspar answer is not exactly answering your question, user3717023.
In Kaspar solution iteration is not repeated but simply skipped (like when using `continue`).

**Proposed solution**

If you want MATLAB to repeat iteration until `myfunction()` is completed successfully use `while`. Look at this this:

```
for ii = 1:30
   disp(ii)

   out = 0;
   while(~out)
       disp('Attempt ...')

       try
           out = myfunction(some_arguments);
       catch
           disp('F****ck!')
       end

       pause(1)
   end

   disp('OK !')           
end
```

If `myfunction` returns its output (which will happen if there was no error) it finishes `while` loop.
Lines with `disp` added for self-descriptivity.

Line with `pause` added for neat output when running example.

**Example**

Run code above with below example of `myfunction()` to check how this solution works:

```
function out = myfunction(x)    
    a = randi(2,1,1) - 1;   % a = 0 or a = 1
    if a==0
        error
    else
        out = magic(3);
    end
end
```

**Example output:**

```
ii =

     1

Attempt ...
F****ck!
Attempt ...
OK !

ii =

     2

Attempt ...
OK !

ii =

     3

Attempt ...
F****ck!
Attempt ...
F****ck!
Attempt ...
F****ck!
Attempt ...
F****ck!
Attempt ...
OK !
```